# How to insert data from csv file to treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter

**I have a treeview in tkinter:**

```
self.progress_view = ttk.Treeview(dataWindow, columns = ('Customer', 'Product'), show = "headings")
    self.progress_view.heading('#1', text = 'Customer')
    self.progress_view.heading('#2', text = 'Product')
    self.progress_view.pack()
```

**and a csv file:**

```
Customer, Product
Customer 1, Almonds
Customer 2, Flaked Almonds
Customer 3, Walnuts
```

**How can I change this code:**

```
def insert_Data_Custom(self):
    self.progress_view.insert("", 'end', values = )
```

to show values based on the csv values?

Customers to fill in customers treeview and products to fill products?

**Conclusion**

Basically import csv data into treeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `import csv`. For the function remove the following code `self.progress_view.insert("", 'end', values = )` and try the following:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        customer = row['Customer']
        product = row['Product']
        self.progress_view.insert("", 0, values=(customer, product))
```

got this from the following link: https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/python/12494/python-import-csv-file-tkinter-table.html